# Electron js webContents.print options not working (always prints on A4 page)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application

I'm working on a cinema ticketing application and when I print ticket it always prints on A4 page. I need the ticket on the small page not on a full-size a4 page. I tried to fix this by using CSS but the results are always the same for page size.

**HTML Template**

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <title>Print Ticket</title>
   <style type="text/css">
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <div style="width: 471px; height: 431px; padding-left: 20px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; font-family: Helvetica; display: flex">
         <div style="  width: 470px;">
            <div style="display: flex;">
               <div style="height: 80px">
                  <h1 style="border-bottom: 6px rgb(147, 47, 60) solid;">YABOUS TICKET</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 470px; display: flex;">
               <div style="max-width: 280px">
                  <div style="width: 310px; height: 70px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                     <div style="width:240px"> <span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 20px">EVENT</span>
                        <br> <span style="font-size: 20px">%event%</span> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="height: 70px; max-width: 290px"> 
                     <span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 20px">HALL</span>
                     <br> <span style="font-size: 20px">%hall%</span> 
                  </div>
                  <div style="height: 70px"> <span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 20px">TICKET NO.</span><span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 20px; margin-left: 90px;">PRICE</span>
                     <br> <span style="font-size: 20px">%seatNo%</span> <span style="font-size: 20px; margin-right: 35px; float: right">%ticketPrice%</span> 
                  </div>
                  <div style="height: 90px; display: flex; align-items: flex-end">
                     <div style="width: 80px; height: 70px"> <span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 15px">FLOOR</span>
                        <br> <span style="color: rgb(69, 68, 67); font-size: 25px"><b>%floor%</b></span> 
                     </div>
                     <div style="width: 80px; height: 70px"> <span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 15px">SEAT</span>
                        <br> <span style="color: rgb(69, 68, 67); font-size: 25px"><b>%seat%</b></span> 
                     </div>
                     <div style="width: 80px; height: 70px"> <span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 15px">ROW</span>
                        <br> <span style="color: rgb(69, 68, 67); font-size: 25px;"><b>%row%</b></span> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                     <span style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(147, 47, 60)">GATE CLOSES 30 MINUTES BEFORE EVENT START</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div style="width: 185px; display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; padding-top: 30px">
                  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; width: 100%">
                     <div>
                        <span style="font-weight: 550; font-size: 16px">EVENT TIME</span>
                        <br>
                        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;"> <span style="font-size: 25px"><b>%time%</b></span> <span style="color: rgb(69, 68, 67); font-size: 20px;">%date%</span> </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="display: flex;justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 200px"> <img src="%qrCode%" width="200"> </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 496px; height: 23px; background: rgb(147, 47, 60); border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;color: white; font-family: Helvetica; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; font-size: 15px; padding-top: 5px; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; ">
         <span>
         <b>WWW.YABOUS.ORG</b>
         </span>
         <span>
         <b>YABOUS</b>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**JS code**

```
    const options = {
        silent: false,
        marginType: 1,
        landscape: true,
        pagesPerSheet: 1,
        collate: true,
        copies: 1,
        printBackground: true,
        pageSize: {
          height: 454,
          width: 471
        }
    }

    let win2 = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 454,
        width: 471,
        icon: __dirname + `/dist/storyteller/assets/favicon.ico`
    });

    win2.setMenu(null);

    win2.loadURL(page);
    // win2.webContents.reload();
    // let win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0]; 

    win2.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        win2.webContents.print(options, (success, failureReason) => {
            if (!success) console.log(failureReason);

            console.log('Print Initiated');
        });
    })
```

**Print Result**

[Print page result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIwPS.jpg)

I need to remove white spaces around the ticket and make the ticket fit the page.

Answer (score 3):

According to Electron's documentation on [`webContents.print ()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprintoptions-callback), the `pageSize` object must only specify a `height` property (although it is declared to provide both `width` and `height` in a `Size` object). Since the docs are ambiguous about the width, I guess it will be calculated to match one of the listed supported page formats if the operating system does not report it to Electron as "supported". Thus, since your `height` does not match any of the supported formats (of your operating system), Electron defaults to A4.

One could argue that the reason for this is that the most consumer printers use one of the listed paper size formats anyway and that mishaps can be prevented by not allowing any other paper format. Also, Chrome doesn't allow to set an arbitrary page height/width via its UI, which probably is also the reason why Electron doesn't implement this (Electron is based on Chromium, the development version of Chrome).

If you have to keep the page size at your special format, the [`webContents.printToPDF ()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprinttopdfoptions) method is probably the next best thing as it allows to specify arbitrary width and height measurements. The linked documentation page gives an example of how to use this function to write to a file. You could then invoke an external PDF reader and print the file from there, but this is content for a new question.

In case you do not have a specialised printer capable of printing on 471mm x 454mm paper, I suggest to stick with A4. If you need the page in PDF format, simply refer to the documentation linked above. And since it seems you're writing some sort of ticketing software: In case you prepare PDF files for customers, also stick with A4 and let the customers fold the paper to the required format. That's how most online-bought tickets in Europe work.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to generate a pdf file from the node express server and open the file URL in an external browser.

Comment: If this has helped you, please mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the grey checkmark icon to the left and/or upvote it.

Comment: Already upvoted. I have less than 15 reputation that's why It's not showing on the answer.

Comment: However, only accepting by clicking the grey checkmark will show others that this question has been answered sufficiently and does not need another answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is incorrect. It's a `Size` object which needs both `width` and `height`. It's just misdocumented. Electron generally seem to have an issue in printing where page size and orientation being completely ignored.

Comment: @m4heshd I'm not sure about this one. The docs (still) state that the parameter (while declared as a `Size` object which declares both parameters, you're right here) can be an object containing `height`, which hints that `width` will be ignored nonetheless. (Disclaimer: Didn't look at the codebase, only speculation!) Anyhow, Chromium will overrule the set page size (as documented and stated in the answer) if the format is not supported by the operating system (and then default to A4). This is not the case with PDF printing.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Try a fiddle with just one property. It'll throw an error.

Comment: @m4heshd Well, you're right -- and the docs are *very* misleading here. However, since this parameter seems to be ignored anyway if it doesn't match a standard paper format specified by the OS, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I agree. It's pointless most of the time either way.

Comment: for anyone like me who is wondering what page size unit is I noticed in windows unit is microns ( 1 inch = 25400 micrometer ) and in linux mint it was inch.